# Vectorization of a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectorization

Is there any representation for the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) of a diagonal matrix $\text{vec}(\text{Diag}(x))$?

For example, for two elements $$\text{vec}(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ 0 &x_2 \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \ . $$

In general case, $\text{vec}(\text{Diag}(x)) = A x$, what is the closed form for matrix $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by "closed form"? Is "the matrix whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $1$ if $j-1 = \left(n+1\right)\left(i-1\right)$ and $0$ otherwise" a closed form? Because that's what $A$ is.

Comment: @darijgrinberg it seems there is a typo in your condition. Should be $i-1 = (n+1)(j-1)$ as in two elements example 1 in the $(4,2)$ entry. However, I am looking for $A$ to be some linear function. For example, $A = \sum_i e_i e_i^T \otimes e_i$, where $e_i$ is the i-th standard basis vector.

Comment: Oops, you are right about $i $ and $j $ being swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n^2}$. Let $e_i, i = 1, ..., n$ be the canonical basis vectors of $\Bbb R^n$, and let $f_j, j = 1, ..., n^2$ be the canonical basis vectors of $\Bbb R^{n^2}$

Then
$$A = \sum_{i=1}^n f_{ni - n + i}\otimes e_i^T$$

Comment: Of course, I should credit danj grinberg for the index formula, where I've handled the reversal by it being the $(j,i)$th entry that is $1$.

Comment: @mzp - You are right - I think it was a typo (I don't remember now). The "$+n$" term should have been "$-n$".

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in{\mathbb R}^{n}\,$ you can express the matrix
$A\in{\mathbb R}^{n^2\times n}\,$ in index notation
$$A_{ij} = \begin{cases}
{\tt1}\quad{\rm if}\;(i+n=j+nj) \\
{\tt0}\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$
This translates verbatim into any language which permits *array comprehensions*.

For example, to reproduce the matrix in your question, in Julia you could write

```
n=2; A = [i+n==j+n*j for i=1:n*n, j=1:n] * 1
4×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  0
 0  0
 0  0
 0  1
```